# Make all boxes vertically and straight when dragged and dropped inside a drop zone

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I have a drag and drop system where you can drop several boxes to a drop zone (see below). I would like to organise each drop so that every box that is dropped goes underneath the previous in a vertically straight line, with a gap between each other.

At the moment, if I drag and drop more than few boxes inside this drop zone, they overlap each other and everything looks really messy. I would like it to work such that each time a box is dropped, regardless of where in the drop zone, it would go underneath the previous one by default.

Note drag and drop is not working on fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/1jkhc0pv/

Drop zone:

```js
function dragInfo(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("Info", event.target.id);
}

function allowDrop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

function drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Info");
  var copyData = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
  copyData.id = "newId";
  event.target.appendChild(copyData);
}

function drag_drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
.columnContent {
  padding-top: 5px;
  width: 129px;
  height: 840px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 3px;
  overflow: auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.dropBox {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 40px;
  height: 140px;
  width: 120px;
  border: 2px dashed;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="columnContent" id="c1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <p>Customer's order</p>

</div>


<div class="dropBox" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragstart="dragInfo(event)" id="dp1" draggable="true">
  <p id="para1">Drag file here</p>
  <div class="leftAlign">
    <img src="pdf.jpg" id="pdfImg" style="visibility: hidden">
    <p1 id="pdfInfo"></p1><br>
  </div>
  <input id="txt1" placeholder="Customer's code" style="visibility: hidden"><br>
  <input id="txt2" placeholder="Customer's size" style="visibility: hidden"><br>
  <input id="txt3" placeholder="Customer's DD" style="visibility: hidden"><br>
  <button id="btn" style="visibility: hidden">Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you update the fiddle/snippet to include some  boxes that are overlapping?

Comment: I tried but drag and drop is not working in fiddle for some reason :(

Comment: Is `.collumnContent` the container for the boxes?

Comment: @ovokuro yes that is the container/dropzone